# links en ruby rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

porque cuando navego por los links de mi página, no me carga por completo todo?

**ejemplo**:

tengo un **dropdown** en mi navbar, si entro a "/" si los puedo abrir  pero si doy click a un enlace cuando me carga la pagina ya no se puede, en consola no recibo error, tengo que presionar "F5".

otro ejemplo:

tengo un **sidebar** con un fondo si navego por los links , el fondo desaparece , tambien no me manda error , pero tengo que presionar F5 para que vuelva a salir.

***En esta imagen yo entre directamnete a http://localhost:3000/panel***
[image]

En esta otra di click al enlace cuenta y el fondo desaparece, tengo que precionar F5

[image]

y eso es para todo, tengo el editor tinymce y tanbien si escribo la url directamente me carga, si entro por un link de la pagina no carga y manda este error:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Agrego esto como respuesta porque aún no tengo puntos suficientes para comentar.

Creo que puede ser relacionado con Turbolinks (JavaScript).

Si estás usando Turbolinks, para que funcione 'correctamente' JavaScript, puedes tener:

```
$(document).on('page:change', function() {
   // JavaScript aquí
})
```

En lugar de:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  console.log( "ready!" );
});
```

Comment: Para **Rails 5**: `$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() { tu JavaScript })`